# Rename publishing site url - How to do it?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to rename a publishing site url, however the edit button is greyed out and the tooltip says it can't be edited.

Any ideas on how to edit it another way? Or is it possible to duplicate the site with a new url?

[image]

When trying to rename the site with PowerShell I get this error also:

> Start-SPOSiteRename : Error Code: -135,This site address can't be changed.
> This site template is not supported for rename.
> At line:9 char:1
> + Start-SPOSiteRename -Identity $url -NewSiteUrl $NewSiteUrl
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-SPOSiteRename], Exception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error Code: -135,This site address can't be changed.
> This site template is not supported for rename.
> ,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.StartSPOSiteRename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, publishing site template is not supported to be renamed.

Currently only the following types of sites can be renamed in SharePoint admin center or using PowerShell:

1. Office 365 group-connected team sites
2. Modern team sites that don't belong to an Office 365 group
3. Communication sites
4. Classic team sites

Here’s your reference: 
[Change a site address.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-site-address)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using powershell Start-SPOSiteRename

```
Start-SPOSiteRename -Identity https://oldURL -NewSiteUrl https://NewURL
```

[Check This](https://office365itpros.com/2019/05/02/sharepoint-online-rename-site-names/)

Comment: Start-SPOSiteRename : Error Code: -135,This site address can't be changed.
This site template is not supported for rename.
At line:9 char:1
+ Start-SPOSiteRename -Identity $url -NewSiteUrl $NewSiteUrl
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-SPOSiteRename], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error Code: -135,This site address can't be changed.
This site template is not supported for rename.
,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.StartSPOSiteRename